# Reading CSV dates with pandas returns datetime instead of Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, timestamp

*Problem description:*

I'm trying to read historical stock prices from CSV format into pandas Dataframe, but one funny thing I have noticed so far - when reading certain row numbers, the dates column type is changed from `pandas.Timestamp` into `datetime` - how does that work? How can I read `pandas.Timestamp` then?

*Minimum reproduction example:*

I have inspected my CSV file, and here is a minimal needed data example from it.

```
import pandas as pd
file = open('temp.csv', 'w')
file.write(
    """Local time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
28.02.2014 02:00:00.000 GMT+0200,1.37067,1.38250,1.36943,1.38042,176839.0313
01.04.2014 03:00:00.000 GMT+0300,1.37742,1.38156,1.37694,1.37937,95386.0703""")
file.close()

data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', parse_dates = ["Local time"])
print(type(data['Local time'][0]))
```

Result: `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

VERSUS

```
import pandas as pd
file = open('temp.csv', 'w')
file.write(
    """Local time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
28.02.2014 02:00:00.000 GMT+0200,1.37067,1.38250,1.36943,1.38042,176839.0313""")
file.close()

data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', parse_dates = ["Local time"])
print(type(data['Local time'][0]))

file = open('temp.csv', 'w')
file.write(
    """Local time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
01.04.2014 03:00:00.000 GMT+0300,1.37742,1.38156,1.37694,1.37937,95386.0703""")
file.close()

data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', parse_dates = ["Local time"])
print(type(data['Local time'][0]))

file = open('temp.csv', 'w')
file.write(
    """Local time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
02.03.2014 02:00:00.000 GMT+0200,1.37620,1.37882,1.37586,1.37745,5616.04
03.03.2014 02:00:00.000 GMT+0200,1.37745,1.37928,1.37264,1.37357,136554.6563
04.03.2014 02:00:00.000 GMT+0200,1.37356,1.37820,1.37211,1.37421,124863.8203""")
file.close()

data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', parse_dates = ["Local time"])
print(type(data['Local time'][0]))
```

Result: `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

Result: `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

Result: `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

*Versions:*

`pandas==1.2.3`
`pandas-datareader==0.9.0`

*Summary:*

I need to read `pandas.Timestamp` because of some latter data manipulations, not `datetime`, and have no ideas what's wrong here - hope, you, guys, can help...

I have created a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40774) as well, but it's not triaged yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which `date_parser` function to be used:

```py
data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', 
                   parse_dates = ["Local time"],
                   date_parser=pd.Timestamp)
```

Output:

```text
>>> data
                  Local time     Open     High      Low    Close       Volume
0  2014-02-03 02:00:00-02:00  1.37620  1.37882  1.37586  1.37745    5616.0400
1  2014-03-03 02:00:00-03:00  1.37745  1.37928  1.37264  1.37357  136554.6563
2  2014-04-03 02:00:00-02:00  1.37356  1.37820  1.37211  1.37421  124863.8203

>>> type(data['Local time'][0])
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

By my observation pandas automatically parses each entry as datetime when timezone are different for individual observation.

The above should work if you really need to use `pd.Timestamp`.

Running the above however also gives me a FutureWarning, which I researched and found to be harmless as of now.

**EDIT**

After a bit more research:

pandas tries to convert a date type column to `DatetimeIndex` for more efficiency in datetime based operations.
But for this pandas needs to have a common timezone for the entire column.

On explicitly trying to convert to `pd.DatetimeIndex`

```text
>>> data
                  Local time     Open     High      Low    Close       Volume
0  2014-02-03 02:00:00-02:00  1.37620  1.37882  1.37586  1.37745    5616.0400
1  2014-03-03 02:00:00-03:00  1.37745  1.37928  1.37264  1.37357  136554.6563
2  2014-04-03 02:00:00-04:00  1.37356  1.37820  1.37211  1.37421  124863.8203

>>> pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Local time'])

ValueError: Array must be all same time zone

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

So when converting to `DatetimeIndex` fails pandas then keeps the data as strings (dtype : object) internally and individual entries to be processed as `datetime`.

Documentation recommends that if timezones in the data are different specify UTC=True, so the timezone would be set as UTC and time values would be changed accordingly.

From Documentation:

> pandas cannot natively represent a column or index with mixed timezones. If your CSV file contains columns with a mixture of timezones, the default result will be an object-dtype column with strings, even with parse_dates.

> To parse the mixed-timezone values as a datetime column, pass a partially-applied to_datetime() with utc=True

In a data that already has the same timezone DatetimeIndex works seamlessly:

```text
>>> data
                 Local time     Open     High      Low    Close       Volume
0 2014-02-03 02:00:00-02:00  1.37620  1.37882  1.37586  1.37745    5616.0400
1 2014-03-03 02:00:00-02:00  1.37745  1.37928  1.37264  1.37357  136554.6563
2 2014-04-03 02:00:00-02:00  1.37356  1.37820  1.37211  1.37421  124863.8203


>>> pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Local time'])

DatetimeIndex(['2014-02-03 02:00:00-02:00', '2014-03-03 02:00:00-02:00',
               '2014-04-03 02:00:00-02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-120)]', name='Local time', freq=None)

>>> type(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Local time'])[0])

<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

References:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-csv-mixed-timezones
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#parse_dates

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I don't understand why the default parsed type with different timezones is datetime, though.
As far as I can see, explicit date_parser works fine, so pandas.read_csv(...) is kind of inconsistent, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think it could be inconsistent unless they have used some sort of randomiser :). In their [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) there is something more about what default `date_parser` does

Comment: By inconsistent, I meant different deduced types - datetime vs Timestamp - for the values with the same data format depending on the value of the timezone.
Thanks, I will read the docs thoroughly.

Comment: @HlibPylypets I would do the same. If I find something solid I would report here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment update, that's awesome.