# How to parse Date and Timestamp columns respectively with Pandas.read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm using Pandas-1.1.5, if an upgrading can resolve my problem, I can do it.

I know how to parse a column into Timestamp type, if there is only one time-liked column in a csv file. i.e like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66941901/10441038):

```
df = pd.read_csv('try-timestamp.csv', parse_dates=['tick_time'], date_parser=pd.Timestamp)
print(type(df['tick_time'][0]))
```

But now I have two time-liked columns, one for Date type, and the other is Timestamp:

```
sample_day,tick_time,data
2022-09-30,22/09/30 09:15:00.446675655,0.273437500
2022-09-30,22/09/30 09:15:00.951579650,0.189697266
```

I want the first column to be parsed into pd.Date type, and the second to pd.Timestamp.

How should I specify parsers for every columns respectively?

Additionally, how to specify a time zone info for them? They are all in a same time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give a list of columns to `parse_dates` like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('try-timestamp.csv', parse_dates=['tick_time', 'sample_day'], date_parser=pd.Timestamp)
```

This will parse both columns as timestamps; there is no "pd.Date" type.

Then I would use `pd.to_datetime` to specify the timezone, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826388/using-time-zone-in-pandas-to-datetime)